# jpamodelgen gerando classes vazias

Tags: java, hibernate, mongodb, spring-data

IDEA
Java 17
MongoDB

Já tentei variar configurações e dependências do hibernate.jpamodelgen mas ou nem gera a classe ou gera vazia desta forma e a classe do Specification não encontra os atributos e fica dando erro.

Classe do Specification

```
package br.com.square.bffconciergeapi.persistence.specification;

import br.com.square.bffconciergeapi.enums.BooleanEnums;
import br.com.square.bffconciergeapi.filters.PersonFilter;
import br.com.square.bffconciergeapi.model.Person;
import br.com.square.bffconciergeapi.model.Person_;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PersonSpecification implements Specification<Person> {


    private PersonFilter filter;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return Specification
                .where(genericWhere())
                .and(byId())
                .and(byDocument())
                .and(byActive())
                .and(byNameLike())
                .toPredicate(root, query, cb);
    }

    private Specification<Person> genericWhere(){
        return (root, query, builder) -> builder.equal(builder.literal(1), 1);
    }
    private Specification<Person> byId() {
        return (root, query, builder) -> filter.getId() != null && !filter.getId().isEmpty() ? builder.equal(root.get(Person_.id), filter.getId()) : null;
    }

    private Specification<Person> byDocument() {
        return (root, query, builder) ->  filter.getDocument() != null && !filter.getDocument().isEmpty() ? builder.equal(root.get(Person_.document), filter.getDocument()) : null;
    }

    private Specification<Person> byActive() {
        return (root, query, builder) -> filter.getActive() != BooleanEnums.BOTH ? builder.equal(root.get(Person_.active), filter.getActive().getBooleanValue()) : null;
    }

    private Specification<Person> byNameLike() {
        return (root, query, builder) -> filter.getName() != null && !filter.getName().isEmpty() ? builder.like(builder.upper(root.get(Person_.name)), "%" + filter.getName().toUpperCase() + "%"): null;
    }

}
```

Clasese Gerada pelo modelgen

```
package br.com.square.bffconciergeapi.model;

import jakarta.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Person.class)
public abstract class Person_ {



}
```

Model

```
package br.com.square.bffconciergeapi.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "persons")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String document;

    private Boolean active;

    // todo implements atributes name, ap, condominium, documents
}
```

POM

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.square</groupId>
    <artifactId>concierge</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>concierge</name>
    <description>bff-concierge-api</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-rc-10</version>
        </dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-jakarta</artifactId>
                            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <defaultOutputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</defaultOutputDirectory>
                    <!--processors>
                        <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                    </processors-->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.